# The system cannot find the path specified...simple php directory

Tags: php, directory

This is the beginning of a script that displays thumbnails, worked fine, but I've broken something about where it is pointing and am now getting some errors. Thanks for your help.

```
$dir = "localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/";
echo "dir is $dir";
$dh = opendir($dir);
```

> Warning:
>   opendir(localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/,localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/)
>   [function.opendir]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code:
>   3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\design.php on line
>   82

dir is localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/string(54)

*FILE* is "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysitee\pages\design.php"

Comment: Try adding `var_dump(__FILE__)`. This will tell you directory in which your script is running from. From there, you can then use a relative path instead.

Comment: Can you also include the output from the `echo "dir is $dir";` line? From the error message you're getting, it seems you have `localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/,localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/` in `$dir` instead of just `localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/`.

Comment: yeah i don't know why it's doing that. i tried to echo another value $dh=opendir($dir) and it leaves a blank.

Comment: `$dh = opendir($dir)` is expected to return `FALSE` (which is displayed as blank) when the directory cannot be opened. My guess is you haven't provided the full code you are using, and you're actually modifying `$dir` between its initialization and the call to `opendir()`.

Comment: Have you tried @Gavin's suggestion? Can you provide the output of `var_dump(__FILE__)`?

Comment: dir is localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/string(54) "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pages\design.php"

Comment: $dir = "../images/thumbnails/"; actually ended up working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dir = "../images/thumbnails/";` actually ended up working

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = "localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/";
```

This line gets evaluated as a relative path. So, it attempts to look for a folder called 'localhost' in your current directory, which it won't find.

If you want it to be evaluated as an absolute path you need to prepend it with http://

```
$dir = "http://localhost/mysite/images/thumbnails/";
```

As Ianzz rightly points out, you cannot open a remote directory.

If you want the path from root, do it this way:

```
$dir = "/images/thumbnails/";
```

The initial backslash is important.

Comment: You cannot `opendir()` an HTTP URL.

Comment: True. I noticed that from your comment on the other answer and made an edit,.

Comment: An absolute path should work according to the PHP docs for `open_dir()`

Comment: True, but it is unlikely that you have successfully guessed the actual absolute path just by discarding half of a relative path, having no idea where it actually starts from.

Comment: Even more unlikely, if you consider that the error message indicates a Windows environment.

Comment: Well, of course I'm not expected to guess his path. If he expects to copy-paste my code as is, it's obviously not going to work. Having him modify the path according this his directory structure isn't asking too much.